# Bootstrap layout pushed down

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

I have been using Twitter Bootstrap 2.1 in my latest design.  For some reason when I add any div elements to the page all of my content/main body gets pushed really far down and extra space is added all over the page, here is a live example and a picture provided as well:
http://www.japaneselanguagefriend.com/application/home.php

[image: Layout being pushed down]

In my CSS in the bootstrap.min.css file I have

```
body{
font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
line-height:20px;
    position:relative;
}
```

and for the div

```
#apDiv1 {
position:relative;
left:439px;
top:669px;
width:300px;
height:670px;
z-index:1;

}
```

I am trying to get a div to display directly over my main content as shown in the picture, but the spacing and more seems to all get messed up somehow.  Any advice or assistance on the problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

UPDATE: So I need to figure out the best way to position my div without affecting my whole layout's spacing. (Thank you Mr.Alien for recommending to adjust the top:size; in my divs style) 
[image]

I am looking for the best way to position it right in with the orange box in the example picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `top:669px;` so cut that down to somewhat `top:30px;`

Comment: Thanks but for some reason I made those changes you recommended and the spacing is still having problems.

Comment: @AoiHana Really? I can see top: 669px; in your stylesheet on your website

Comment: You are right! I re uploaded the .css file.  It did fix it, but the only problem is how would I position my div now? Currently it is not where I need it to be, I think that is why I had the top-size fixed to that height.  Any ideas on positioning my div without affecting the spacing of my whole layout? Thanks so much!

Comment: where you want to position your div?

Comment: Go ahead and refresh this page, I added an update with a picture.  I am trying to center the div in on a certain area on my website.  Absolute position works but whenever the browsers screen is re sized the div moves along with the browser..

Comment: why use `position: absolute;`? simply use position relative, and use `margin: auto;` to bring it in center, but actually your website is not responsive, it is not resizing on changing the viewport size and hence you are facing these problems

Comment: because you are using so big fixed widths, you need to learn responsive design

Comment: That sounds good, any recommendations on where to start learning correct responsive design?

Comment: check out some good books, say this one is good http://www.amazon.com/Adaptive-Web-Design-Experiences-Progressive/dp/098358950X check out the exercise files, It will show you how the responsive designs work

Comment: Thank you very much for everything!